# Converting an int to bytes for serial communication

Tags: python, int, byte, modbus, rs485

I need to send a modified version of Airbus (a weird modified version of Modbus) hex commands over RS485 to a serial device. The command that I want to send is 0x8181521500005315. I'm able to successfully send the command as a literal in the form:

```
b'\x81\x81\x15\x21\x00\x00\x53\x15'
```

but I'd like to somehow convert an int variable into the same format.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def advancedWriteR(param):
command = (0x818152*0x10000000000 + param*0x100000000 + genECC('r', param))

msg =command.to_bytes(8, byteorder='big')

ser.write(msg)
```

The strange thing is that msg becomes:

```
b'\x81\x81R\x15\x00\x00S\x15'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your `param` value? And what does the function `genECC()` do?

Comment: If you replace "R" by its hex equivalent "\x52" and "S" by "\x53" then you'll see that b'\x81\x81R\x15\x00\x00S\x15' is exactly the same as b'\x81\x81\x52\x15\x00\x00\x53\x15'.  Does that help you to understand what's happening?

Comment: The param value and the genECC function are for creating the int variable.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b'\x81\x81R\x15\x00\x00S\x15' is exactly 
b'\x81\x81\52\x15\x00\x00\53\x15'

You can get them back and force with the *struct* module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>Q', 0x8181521500005315)
b'\x81\x81R\x15\x00\x00S\x15'
>>> struct.unpack('>Q', b'\x81\x81R\x15\x00\x00S\x15')
(9331830153036190485,)
>>> '0x{:x}'.format(9331830153036190485)
'0x8181521500005315'
```

Comment: or you can use the built-in `to_bytes` as OP did in his question and not bother with `struct`.  I think OP already did what he wants to do, but did not understand how Python displayed the returned value (a mixture of ASCII-printable characters and escaped hex values).